# Understanding Asp.net MVC Route config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am reading an online article which show the following router definition:-

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.MapRoute(null,
205
"",
new {
controller = "Product", action = "List",
category = (string)null, page = 1
}
);
routes.MapRoute(null,
"Page{page}",
new { controller = "Product", action = "List", category =
(string)null },
new { page = @"\d+" }
);
```

But I cannot understand what does this router rules mean and how they are going to work, i usually do not modify the router rules and keep the default definition as-is?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I don't really want to create a new application and test the route out. Assuming that it doesn't have any unforeseen issues then what it's doing is this:

routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}"); <- tells it to ignore attempts to download resource files.

the null where the route name should be. They aren't assigning a name. I'm guessing the 205 is a product id, the "" action defaults to "List", if you don't add a category to the query string then it's assigned a null which is then casted into a string. That seems a bit odd to me. Without testing, it either gives an empty string or a null value. The page would be for navigating through pages. Quite a bit of this route is dependent on a specific server side action.

```
routes.MapRoute(null,
205
"",
new {
controller = "Product", action = "List",
category = (string)null, page = 1
}
);
```

The last entry sets the default values for the controller action. The one new piece is the "new { page = @"\d+" } which is regex expression that limits the valid value to a digit between 0-9 and the + requires 1 or more digits. As a extra tidbit, the new {} <- where custom routerhandler methods would be associated with a route if you wanted to do some more specific route handling. Search for IRouteHandler for details.

```
routes.MapRoute(null,
"Page{page}",
new { controller = "Product", action = "List", category =
(string)null },
new { page = @"\d+" }
);
```

I hope this helps. Routing can be a real pain sometimes.